# Смена + на - при клике

Tags: javascript, css, click

есть код HTML

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $(".aft-original-text").on('click', function() {
    $(".aft-original-text-content").toggle();
  });
});
```

```html
<div class="aft-original-text aft-inline-divs">
  <div class="aft-original-text-header aft-action-toggl">
    <pre> ?php echo __("Original Campaign",'affiliatewp-mcc')? </pre>
  </div>
  <div class="aft-original-text-content"><pre> ?php echo $content ?></pre></div>
</div>
```

[image: визуально]

как прилепить в этот код к header +/-, чтобы они менялись, когда content виден то это минус, когда скрыт то плюс? пожалуйста подскажите.

Comment: Вижу, у вас контент будет получаться через php... под "контент виден" имеется в виду обычное переключение между display: block; и display: none; или должен быть еще вариант, если контент вообще не получен?

Comment: обычное переключение между display: block; и display: none

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так пойдет? =)

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $(".aft-original-text").on('click', function() {
    $(".aft-original-text-content").toggle();
    let span = $(".aft-action-toggl span");
    span.html(span.html() === '[-]' ?'[+]':'[-]');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="aft-original-text aft-inline-divs">
  <div class="aft-original-text-header aft-action-toggl">
    <pre> ?php echo __("Original Campaign",'affiliatewp-mcc')? <span>[-]</span></pre>
  </div>
  <div class="aft-original-text-content">
    <pre> ?php echo $content ? </pre>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: да, конечно) спасибо огромное, единственное, я поменяла немного span.html(span.html() === '+' ?'-':'+'). а так все отлично:)